# mysql multiple rows update taking longer than it should

Tags: php, mysqli

I am running a simple update on my database, that is fed from a form that contains approximately 100 check boxes. So it loops about 100 times, but takes close to 10 seconds to do so. As a form only passes the checked checkboxes, I set all of the values in the 'selected column' to 0 first and then set selected to 1 based on a passed in checkbox id. I feel like this should take a couple seconds max, not 10.

Am I doing something that is causing the process to drag?

```
if (isset($_POST['validCall']))
{
    $sql = "UPDATE salesTable SET selected = 0 WHERE programID = ?";

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) 
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['program']);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }

    foreach($_POST as $key =>$value)
    {
        if ($key != "validCall" && $key != "program")
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE salesTable SET selected = 1 WHERE ID = ?";

            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) 
            {
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $key);

                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 100 inserts? you only need ONE

Comment: you don't have to prepare same sql query every loops

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate on how to only insert once?

Answer (score 0):

changing the foreach so it only runs one query

```
$ids=array();
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if ($key != "validCall" && $key != "program"){
        $ids[] = $key; // get the ids to use
    }
}


// creates a string containing ?...
$clause = implode(',',array_fill(0,count($ids),'?'));


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( "UPDATE salesTable SET selected = 1 WHERE ID = ($clause)";

call_user_func_array(array(
        $stmt,
        'bind_param'
),$ids);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE salesTable SET selected = 1 WHERE ID = ?";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $key);

    foreach($_POST as $key =>$value)
    {
        if ($key != "validCall" && $key != "program")
        {            
            $stmt->execute();     
        }
    }
}

$stmt->close();
```

Hope this helps :)